# Decimal accuracy of output layer in keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I am working on a project that predicts drug synergy values based on various input features related to them. The synergy values are floating point numbers and so I would like to set an accuracy range for my neural network. 
eg - Say the actual value is 1.342423 and my model predicts 1.30123 then the output this should be treated as correct ouput.
In other words I would like to limit the amount of decimal places that are checked to compare the actual answer and the predicted answer. 
Neural Net :

```
model = Sequential()
act = 'relu'
model.add(Dense(430, input_shape=(3,)))
model.add(Activation(act))

model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Activation(act))
model.add(Dropout(0.42))

model.add(Dense(148))
model.add(Activation(act))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Complete source code for learning and train/test data :
https://github.com/tanmay-edgelord/Drug-Synergy-Models/blob/master
Please ask for any additional details that are required
(Using Keras with TensorFlow backend)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a [custom metric](https://keras.io/metrics/#custom-metrics):

```
import keras.backend as K

def myAccuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    diff = K.abs(y_true-y_pred) #absolute difference between correct and predicted values
    correct = K.less(diff,0.05) #tensor with 0 for false values and 1 for true values
    return K.mean(correct) #sum all 1's and divide by the total.
```

Then use it in the model compilation:

```
model.compile(metrics=[myAccuracy],....)
```

Comment: Because you want a value between 0 and 1 for the accuracy, right? All those calculations work on "tensors" (matrices with all predictions at once). The `correct` variable is a tensor with lots of 0's and lots of 1's. If they're all ones, accuracy is one. If they're all 0, accuracy is 0. If half of them are 1, accuracy is 0.5.

Comment: I still do not fully understand. What will it return for say y_true = 3.10142 and y_pred = 3.01231

Comment: Models work with a lot of data at the same time, you will have things like `y_true=[3.10, 2.50, 4.10]` and `y_pred=[3.01,2.47,4.16]`. The result will be the mean value of `[False,True,False] = 33%`. -- You can adjust the `0.05` to a bigger value.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation